# Extract RAR from MSBUILD script

Tags: msbuild, rar

I know that using MSBuild Extension Pack I can decompress Zip files, but in my project I need to decompress a RAR file.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Exec to extract archive by winrar.exe/rar.exe.
If you have installed WinRar you can extract its installdir from registry otherwise specify where you rar.exe is located.

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="4.0">

<Target Name="ExtractRar">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <RarExe>$(registry:HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Winrar@exe32)</RarExe>
        <archive>E:\sample.rar</archive>
        <targetDir>E:\ExtratedArchive\</targetDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="&quot;$(RarExe)&quot; x &quot;$(archive)&quot; &quot;$(targetDir)&quot;" /> 
</Target>

</Project>
```

Comment: @Fernando, if Palo answered your question, please put a checkmark next to his answer.